# Select all and click Assign

Tags: java, angularjs

Currently I am getting an error that when I click on select all students to be able to click the assign button to be able to jump from the Unassigned tab to the Assigned tab, but now when I click on it, I can't click the assign button
And when I click to select each one, it can be assigned

here my js and html code

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in tableData">
                        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="student.selected"
                            ng-change="updateSelectedStudents(student)"
                            ng-checked="selectAll"></td>
                        <td ng-model="form.student.studentId">{{ student.studentId
                            }}</td>
                        <td ng-model="form.student.semester.semesterId"
                            class="d-none d-xl-table-cell">{{
                            student.semester.semesterId }}</td>
                        <td ng-model="form.student.subjectId"><span
                            class="badge bg-success">{{ student.subjectId }}</span></td>
                        <td ng-model="form.student.totalFee"
                            class="d-none d-md-table-cell">{{ student.totalFee }}</td>
                        <td class="d-none d-md-table-cell"><select
                            ng-model="form.employees.employeeId" 
                            class="form-select" ng-show="selectAll || student.selected" >
                                <option ng-repeat="x in employees" value="{{x}}">{{
                                    x.employeeId }}</option>
                        </select></td>

                        <td ng-model="form.student.imported.importedFileName"
                            class="d-none d-md-table-cell">{{
                            student.imported.importedFileName }}</td>
                    </tr>
```

```
JS
// The function updates the state of the checkboxes in the body based on the value of $scope.selectAll
  $scope.toggleSelectAll = function() {
    $scope.tableData.forEach(function(student) {
      student.selected = $scope.selectAll;
    });
    $scope.updateSelectedEmployees(); // Update HR code status when all checkboxes are selected
  };

// Function to update the list of selected students
$scope.updateSelectedStudents = function(student) {
  if (!student.selected && $scope.selectAll) {
    $scope.selectAll = false;
  } else if (student.selected) {
    $scope.selectedStudents.push(student);
  } else {
    var index = $scope.selectedStudents.findIndex(function(selectedStudent) {
      return selectedStudent.studentId === student.studentId;
    });
    $scope.selectedStudents.splice(index, 1);
  }
  $scope.updateSelectedEmployees(); // Update HR code status when selecting each checkbox
};

// Function to update personnel code for selected students
$scope.updateSelectedEmployees = function() {
  var selectedStudentsCount = $scope.selectedStudents.length;
  $scope.allSelected = (selectedStudentsCount === $scope.tableData.length);
  var selectedEmployeeId = $scope.form.employees.employeeId;
  $scope.selectedStudents.forEach(function(student) {
    if (student.employee) {
      student.employee.employeeId = selectedEmployeeId;
    }
  });
};

// Function to assign students from "Unassigned" table to "Assigned" table
$scope.assignStudents = function() {
  // Check if the personnel code is selected or not
  if (!$scope.form.employees.employeeId) {
    // Display an error message if the personnel code is not selected
    alert("Please select personnel code before assigning!");
    return;
  }

  // Loop through the list of students in the tableData . array
  for (var i = $scope.tableData.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var student = $scope.tableData[i];
    // Check if student is selected or not
    if (student.selected) {
      // Set employeeId for assigned student
      student.employee = JSON.parse($scope.form.employees.employeeId);
      var url = `/rest/student/` + student.studentId;
      $http.put(url, student).then(function(resp) {
        var index = $scope.tableData.findIndex(function(item) {
          return item.studentId == student.studentId;
        });
        console.log("Student update successful", resp);
        $scope.showStudents();
        $scope.showStudents2();
        $scope.disableAssignButton = true;
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Update student failed", error);
        alert("Assignment failed!");
      });
    }
  }
  alert("Assignment successful!");
  $scope.selectedStudents = []; // Clear the selected student list
  $scope.selectAll = false; // Reset state to select all checkboxes
};
```

The result i want is when i click select all it can be assigned as if i select each student
Meaning all selected students will jump from unassigned tab to assigned